# Using an interface classifier in a UML Class Diagram

Tags: class, architecture, interface, uml

I am trying to implement an UML Class Diagram and I would like to use an *interface* classifier **CreateItem** to inform a developer that (that rappresents an input web form), in order to populate an attribute TitleI in a class **Item**, he/she MUST use one or more TitleO of a class **Object**. That is, I would like to indicate that using a web form **CreateItem** you can "compose" a **Item** TitleI (TitleI is a string) exclusively searching and adding to it one or more **Object** TitleO (TitleO is a string).

It should working as "composing" the StackOverflow *Tags* "string" when you Ask a new question. The only difference is that I would like to create a Title string made by those Tags.

I "learned" to solve part of my issue in thinking this way:

```
< < interface > > **CreateItem** is a *realization* of **Item**
```

Then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can depict the composition/aggregation using respective relationships. You can use the dependency relationship to depict creation. If this doesn't help, try to formulate your question in other way or to be more precise and I will try to answer.